# pyspark create multiple columns from values of existing column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like so:

```
+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|id  |point|count|
+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|id_1|5    |9    |
|id_2|5    |1    |
|id_3|4    |3    |
|id_1|3    |3    |
|id_2|4    |3    |
```

The id-point pairs are unique.
I would like to group by id and create columns from the point column with values from the count column like so:

```
+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|id  |point_3|point_4|point_5|
+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|id_1|3      |0      |9
|id_2|0      |3      |1
|id_3|0      |3      |0
```

If  you can guide me on how to start this or in which direction to start going, it would be much appreciated. I feel stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use pivot to achieve the required result:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

#sample dataframe
in_values = [("id_1", 5, 9), ("id_2", 5, 1), ("id_3", 4, 3), ("id_1", 3, 3), ("id_2", 4, 3)]
in_df = spark.createDataFrame(in_values, "id string, point int, count int")

out_df = in_df.groupby("id").pivot("point").agg(sum("count"))

# To replace null by 0
out_df = out_df.na.fill(0)

# To rename columns
columns_to_rename = out_df.columns
columns_to_rename.remove("id")

for col in columns_to_rename:
    out_df = out_df.withColumnRenamed(col, f"point_{col}")

out_df.show()

+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  id|point_3|point_4|point_5|
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|id_2|      0|      3|      1|
|id_1|      3|      0|      9|
|id_3|      0|      3|      0|
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```